# Material UI tab navigation between TextFields with InputAdornment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to disable "focus" event from happening on input adornments of MaterialUI Text Fields.

So if I have 2 fields with input adornments I want to be able to switch between them using just a single Tab press, avoiding focusing on the input adornment. Is this even possible without creating complex styling?

Currently you can see this(unfavorable) behavior in MUI docs: https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that like the following.

Using [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

```
...

            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                  tabIndex={-1}
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
...
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what was needed!